# How can I add securityToken to this resultactivity?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

D/OkHttp: {"code":60202,"message":"Token required"}

This is server error problem.
I want solve code in this resultactivity.
I already setting securityToken here, but how can I add securityToken to request()?

````
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        val securityToken = SaveSharedPreference.getUserInfo(this)

        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


                Client.retrofitService.request(result.contents).enqueue(object : Callback<String?> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<String?>, t: Throwable) {

                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<String?>?,
                        response: Response<String?>?
                    ) {
                        if (response?.isSuccessful == false) {
                            val er = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(), ErrorResponse::class.java)
                            Log.d(_tag, "${er.code}:${er.message}")
                            if (er.code == 60201 || er.code== 60202)
                          {
                                Toast.makeText(this@Qrcode, "토큰이 유효하지 않습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                            } else if (securityToken !=null) {
                            Log.d(_tag, "status: ${response?.code()}. body: ${response?.body()}")

                        }


                    }

                    }

                })
            }

}```
````

Comment: Is the securityToken required as a Header?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional parameter in your request like:

```
interface RetrofitService {  
    @GET("/request")
    request(@Query("parameter") parameter: String, @Header("Security-Token") securityToken: String): Call<String>
}
```

Or,

You can build an OkHttpClient for your Retrofit in creating RetrofitService:

RetrofitService :

```
interface RetrofitService {  
    @GET("/request")
    request(@Query("parameter") parameter): Call<String>
}
```

Retrofit Builder:

```
val securityToken = "securityTokenString"

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request()

        val newRequestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
            .header("Security-Token", securityToken)

        chain.proceed(newRequestBuilder.build())
    }

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

val retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
```